# Client for SOAP (ASMX) web-service without proxy

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, channelfactory

I have two clients. The first one is auto-generated proxy like this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Web.Services", "4.0.30319.18408")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="Service1", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
public partial class Service1 : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/Get", RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public Data[] Get(int x) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("InMotion_Wholesaler_FromTimestampAdv", new object[] {
                    login,
                    password,
                    timestamp});
        return ((InmWholesaler[])(results[0]));
    }
```

It works and returns list of Data with elements.

The second one like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
[WebServiceBinding(Name = "Service1", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [SoapDocumentMethod(
        "http://tempuri.org/Get",
        RequestNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/",
        ResponseNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/",
        Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal,
        ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    Data[] Get(int x);
}

    private IService1 Service1
    {
        get
        {
            var soap12Binding = new CustomBinding(
                new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12, Encoding.UTF8)
                {
                    ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
                    {
                        MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue,
                        MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue,
                        MaxDepth = int.MaxValue,
                        MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue,
                        MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue
                    },
                },
                new HttpTransportBindingElement
                {
                    MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue
                });

            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(soap12Binding, new EndpointAddress(url));

            return channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        }
    }
```

And this client returns empty list (not null).

Can I create a client by ChannelFactory? What is my mistake?

Comment: Use the binding from the autogenerated proxy. Watch the client constructor overloads. The default binding that works when you create a client with the parameterless constructor should be in your app.config. You can reconstruct that in your code. Maybe it does not support custom bindings.

Comment: There are not any binding settings in the app.config. And constructor sets only useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly property.